# Usando FTPClient não consigo enviar arquivo para servidor FTP. Problema com permissão

Tags: java, android, ftp, permissões

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo android que faz acesso a um servidor FTP onde guardo arquivos de backup. Estou usando como base [nesse](http://www.devmedia.com.br/desenvolvendo-um-cliente-ftp/3547) tutorial. O servidor FTP é o CesarFTP. O sistema operacional é um Windows Server 2008 R2.

Eu faço cópias de arquivos pelo FTP sem problemas. Porém, quando tento enviar um arquivo simplesmente este não é gravado. O código de retorno do FTP é 550. Ou seja, aparentemente tenho problemas relacionados a permissão da pasta, mas quando fiz um teste de envio com um programa destinado a gerenciar arquivos por FTP este conseguiu enviar e receber arquivos sem problemas. Verifiquei as permissões tanto na pasta quanto no Cesar e todas as permissões que posso dar por meio da interface de segurança foram dadas. Porém, ao visualizar as permissões da pasta com o CuteFTP esta está com permissão 744. Por esta razão, acredito que sempre que eu efetuo login no servidor FTP pelo meu aplicativo eu recebo permissão publica e por isto só consigo efetuar leitura na pasta.

Tentei colocar a permissão da pasta como, no mínimo, 766, mas não tive sucesso. Então se eu não resolver trocando a permissão desta pasta, acredito que pode ter alguma forma de eu me autenticar no servidor FTP de forma a conseguir acessar o perfil que tem acesso total a pasta, como ocorre com programas destinados a gerenciar FTP.

Como fazer isto ou algo que solucione a questão da permissão na pasta?

Comment: Se você envia com um outro cliente ftp (Filezilla, por exemplo) funciona normalmente?

Comment: Exatamente. Com o Filezilla mesmo que testei. O arquivo é enviado sem problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não consegui identificar uma forma de resolver esse problema com permissão por meio do código nem pelas configurações do Windows Server 2008 R2. Solucionei o problema trocando o SO do servidor.